# Write an entire program to a file in C

Tags: c, file, output

I'm quite new to C programming, but I'm starting to get the hang of it.
For a school assignment, I have written a code in C to play Blackjack.
One of the requirements for the assignment, is that is has to have an option that saves the entire output (everything that's shown in cmd when the program is build and run).
I can't find how to do this anywhere.

Is there a way to write the entire output into a file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `stdout` and `stderr` are what are shown in the command entry window.

Comment: you could either store it somewhere in your program or just write stdout to a file. like this MyProgram > out.log

Comment: @ruler501 What do you mean by writing stdout to a file? I haven't used stdout before, but it seems like it's an alternative to printf(), as in 
_printf( "hello world\n" );_  
_fprintf( stdout, "hello world\n" );_  
What do you mean by MyProgram > out.log ?
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: This really is not a `C` problem, but a `cmd` shell one.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to achieve what you want.

1. Use a file. This is the way I recommend. You will need the functions [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/?kw=fopen) to open a file and [enter link description here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/?kw=fprintf) to print the data in the file. I suggest you read the documentation of the functions in the links and look at the examples.
2. Redirect stdout to a file using [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/?kw=freopen). This basically puts everything that you see now in the console in a file, by adding just one line.
3. Redirect the output of the program in a file. This is more a shell thing than a C programming technique, but I think it is worth mentioning. In an *NIX environment, the command `./a.out > file.txt` will redirect the output of a.out to a file called file.txt in a similar manner freopen does.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help. Both the first and the second option seem alright, but there's still a problem though. Whether or not the program has to be saved to a file must be declared at the end of the program. The thing with both these options is that I'll have to name a file at the start of the program (when I open the file). Is there a way to decide to save it and enter a name at the end of the program? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The program must know where to save the data (which file to open), so no, you cannot open the file after the output has been generated, and I don't see why you MUST do this. You can simply change the way the program works and ask for the file name at the beginning. However, if you really have to do it this way, you must generate the output and store it somehow. You can either store the output in a char array and write it to a file at the end, or create a temporary file and using some system calls rename it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the stdout and stderr to a file when you build and run. For example, on Linux using the bash shell you can do try this (where the "build_script" is what you use to build and the "a.exe" is the program name):

```
$ ./build_script >& build_out.txt
$ ./a.exe >& run_out.txt &
```

The ">&" tells bash to pipe both stdout and stderr to the file. The final "&" in the second line tells bash to run the program in the background. It's hard to tell if this answer will suit your purposes since it's not clear exactly how the game is played from what you have posted. E.g., if you need to use stdin/stdout to play the game then maybe piping the "a.exe" stdout to a file might not work...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming simple output redirection is not an option:

```
$ app > file.txt
```

Probably, you are using `printf` to print data to console. Instead of `printf`, you can use `fprintf`. `fprintf` can write data to an arbitrary file, just like `printf` does to the standard output (which is also a file), in this case the console.

You must first open the file where you will write the output. The command `fopen` will do this for you:

```
// this will open or create the file as text to write data.
FILE *f = fopen("my-file.txt", "w");
```

With the `f` variable (which you should check for `NULL` in case of error), you can pass it to `fprintf` to write data:

```
fprintf(f, "my super string: %s", string);
```

Note that despite the first argument being a `FILE*`, everything else behaves like `printf`. Actually you can think of `printf` as a wrapper where the first argument of the `fprintf` is always `stdout`.

Do not forget to close your file after you write data!

```
fclose(f);
```

This can be done once, after all the data is written to file.

Check the man pages for more info about these commands.

There are more complex (not that much actually) ways of accomplishing this, like using `freopen`, but I'm leaving this out of the answer. If you need more, update your answer.

**EDIT**

In your comment, you said you must save or not the output to a file at the end of the program. Well, the file management stuff above you still be usefull. The changes are the following:

You must store the output somewhere in order to decide whether to write to a file or not at the end of the program. Probably you are doing some data formatting with `printf`. You will have to change your calls from `printf` to `snprintf`. This command will write your data to a string, just as `printf` does prior to output it to the `stdout`, but it will skip the print-to-output- part.

Then, store the buffer at a list of strings and at the end of the program you write this list to the file or not.

This has some complications: you need a list of strings (a dynamically allocated array of arrays will be enough, actually); how big must your buffer be?

`snprintf` will return the size required to print the passed data to the buffer, no matter if the buffer is larger or smaller then the given one. But, if it is smaller, you will have to increase its size (reallocating it) and call again `snprintf`:

```
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 41); // 40 chars + \0!
int size;
if ( size = snprintf(buffer, 41, "your format here", args) > 40 ) {
    buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
    snprintf(buffer, size + 1, "your format here", args);
}
// now your buffer have the correct data!
// print it to stdout!
puts(buffer);
// store it at the string list.
// execise!
```

Is left as an exercise wrapping this piece of code in a command to avoid repeat it everywhere you print anything. Also, it is an exercise to create the list of strings.

When you decide to write data to file, instead of use `fprintf` you can use `fputs`, as data is already formatted.

I don't know if there is an easier way. I think not.

Comment: Hello! The way you describe seems alright, but there's still a problem though. Whether or not the program has to be saved to a file must be declared at the end of the program. The thing with this option is that I'll have to name a file at the start of the program (when I open the file). Is there a way to decide to save it and enter a name at the end of the program? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at may edit. I'm strongly assuming this as an exercise to be accomplished with C and only. Hope it helps.